# AWS S3 permission to upload, download and delete only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an IAM user that I want to give permission to only delete, upload and download files from a S3 bucket using AWS SDK.

I have created the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "Stmt",
          "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:user/xxxxx"
            ]
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

But it fails performing any of those actions. It only works when I attach a policy to the user through the IAM management console. But doing so gives more power than I want to give. It is actually called AmazonS3FullAccess, which indeed gives full access to S3.

Is there any way to do this without giving full access?

Comment: Instead of using a pre-built IAM role like `AmazonS3FullAccess` build a custom IAM role with the specific permissions you want to provide.

Comment: That works! Post this comment as answer so I can mark as correct asnwer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a pre-built IAM role like `AmazonS3FullAccess` build a custom IAM role with the specific permissions you want to provide.